Qt Creator doesn't understand a valid QML module import
I have a CMake (3.22.1) project and I have added my QML (Qt SDK 6.5.5) module like this:
qt_add_qml_module(MyQmlModule
    URI MyQmlModule
    VERSION 1.0
    RESOURCE_PREFIX /
    QML_FILES ${QML_SOURCE_FILES}
)

While the project builds and works just fine, Qt Creator (13.0.0, 14.0.0) doesn't understand the import and it annoys me:

I need this import, because otherwise my singleton QML objects don't work:
set_source_files_properties(MySingleton.qml PROPERTIES QT_QML_SINGLETON_TYPE TRUE)

The error message says that QML_IMPORT_PATH should be in CMakeCache.txt, but not sure if that's related to this particular case as the project actually works.
Is there a way to make Qt Creator to understand my import or is it just a bug?

Placing these two lines in your main CMakeLists would probably tackle the problem:
set(QT_QML_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/qml" CACHE PATH "Install path for QML" FORCE)
set(QML_IMPORT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/qml CACHE STRING "Extra QML Import Paths" FORCE)

As it seems like a cash error otherwise the project would not have run in the first place. Set the path for QMLs, store it as a cash, and then import it from the specified path.

Didn't help, unfortunately. I'm not sure how this is supposed to work as I guess the import is based on URI, which means that there might not be a corresponding (similarily named output file) file at all. This mapping is handled in the auto-generated qmldir-files.

@juzzlin check if it helps: clean the build, add above lines, run cmake, build and run cmake one again.

check this project in development branch.

Can you import main_module in your Main_Page.qml so that Qt Creator understands it? I need to do that in order to get Singletons loaded. It's another topic why they don't just work without the import like all other QML objects.

Oh, sorry...I missed that development branch :D

Ok, now after having cleaned and rebuilt everything the annotation has changed to "QML module contains C++ plugins" so your suggestion seems to have fixed the original issue, at least :)

@juzzlin Not sure why but QML module contains C++ plugins disappears after  a while. Maybe it is Some cmake runs, builds..

The naming rule of the Qml module quite complicated. But i can tell you for short.

Given the above image, let's assume you want to use your extra module in Main_page qml file, you should name the URI at line 3 with the same folder name "extra"
Whenever we import a module like "import A.B", the QML engine starts looking up from the build directory and it will try to find the folder A, then the folder B. The qmldir should be placed under /A/B
